# Table Structure for a Map system like Fallensword

Tags: sql

I need help to structure a Map system like fallensword.com. Basically, there are different maps you can move around on. (You choose a map you start on then you can move around) And on the map there are for example caves, that you can enter, and you get on another map, etc.

How do I structure that SQL? I guess I need a x/y colum, but then what. What more should I have, there are sometimes NPC (that you attack) and sometimes NPC that you get a quest from, and sometimes, a house/cave or something (you can enter/get quest out of)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A kd tree or a quadtree can help you much to solve your problem. A quadtree reduces the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. It's used in many maps applications like bing or google maps. A good start is Nick's spatial index quadtree hilbert curve blog. You can use mysql with a spatial index but if you want to write a game this isn't the right place to ask. There is game.stackexchange.